# Application Crash on loading listview inonly OS 4.0 in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on an application which runs superbly on my each and every device but crashes on Android 4.0 of client. Below are the logs:

Please look for this line "I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 160 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." in logs.

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/ActivityManager(  395): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher u=0} from pid 395
I/ActivityManager(  395): No longer want com.noshufou.android.su (pid 32427): hidden #16
I/ActivityManager(  395): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.weg.ecatalogfragment/.SplashScreen u=0} from pid 817
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
D/dalvikvm(  395): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1465K, 38% free 15471K/24775K, paused 74ms, total 74ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  395): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.214MB for 1048592-byte allocation
I/ActivityManager(  395): Start proc com.weg.ecatalogfragment for activity com.weg.ecatalogfragment/.SplashScreen: pid=361 uid=10111 gids={3003, 1015, 1023, 1028}
E/Trace   (  361): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
D/libEGL  (  361): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
D/libEGL  (  361): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
D/libEGL  (  361): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
D/OpenGLRenderer(  361): Enabling debug mode 0
I/ActivityManager(  395): Displayed com.weg.ecatalogfragment/.SplashScreen: +476ms
V/        (  395): void cb_onMotion(uint16_t)
I/ActivityManager(  395): START {flg=0x4000000 cmp=com.weg.ecatalogfragment/.ECatalogFragmentActivity u=0} from pid 361
I/System.out(  361): gdfgdgcvbccccccccccccccccccc 0
D/dalvikvm(  361): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1477K, 31% free 5683K/8195K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 19ms
I/ActivityManager(  395): Displayed com.weg.ecatalogfragment/.ECatalogFragmentActivity: +345ms
I/fdhttpd (29030): battery level:85 plugged:0
W/InputMethodManagerService(  395): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41edb798 attribute=null
W/InputMethodManagerService(  395): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41f32a40 attribute=null
V/        (  395): void cb_onMotion(uint16_t)
D/dalvikvm(  361): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1060K, 25% free 6420K/8455K, paused 2ms+6ms, total 27ms
W/InputMethodManagerService(  395): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@426f5a98 attribute=null
W/InputMethodManagerService(  395): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41f88e20 attribute=null
W/InputMethodManagerService(  395): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41f60498 attribute=null
D/dalvikvm(  361): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1636K, 29% free 6575K/9159K, paused 2ms+17ms, total 44ms
I/System.out(  361): gdfgdgcvbccccccccccccccccccc 0
D/dalvikvm(  361): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 825K, 37% free 5893K/9287K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  361): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.937MB for 80656-byte allocation
I/ActivityManager(  395): Start proc android.process.acore for content provider com.android.providers.contacts/.ContactsProvider2: pid=396 uid=10001 gids={3003, 1015, 1023, 1028}
W/InputMethodManagerService(  395): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4250a310 attribute=null
E/Trace   (  396): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
I/ActivityThread(  396): Pub call_log: com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider
I/ActivityThread(  396): Pub com.android.voicemail: com.android.providers.contacts.VoicemailContentProvider
I/ActivityThread(  396): Pub user_dictionary: com.android.providers.userdictionary.UserDictionaryProvider
I/ActivityThread(  396): Pub applications: com.android.providers.applications.ApplicationsProvider
I/ActivityThread(  396): Pub contacts;com.android.contacts: com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2
I/ActivityManager(  395): No longer want com.tmobile.thememanager (pid 32525): hidden #16
D/dalvikvm(  395): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1610K, 41% free 15343K/25863K, paused 7ms+7ms, total 94ms
**I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 160 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2723.0ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2713.7ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2704.3ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2694.8ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2685.5ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2675.9ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2666.6ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2656.8ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2647.7ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2638.3ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2628.7ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2619.3ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2609.9ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2600.5ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2591.1ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2581.6ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2572.2ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2562.7ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2553.0ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2543.7ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2534.3ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2524.7ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2515.3ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2505.9ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2496.3ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2486.9ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2477.4ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2468.0ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2458.4ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2449.0ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2439.5ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2429.9ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2420.4ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2411.0ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2401.5ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2391.4ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2382.5ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2373.1ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2363.6ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2354.1ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2344.6ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2335.1ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2325.6ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2316.3ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2306.8ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2297.3ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2287.8ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2278.3ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2268.8ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2259.4ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2249.9ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
I/InputDispatcher(  395): Window 'Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}' spent 2230.5ms processing the last input event: MotionEvent(action=2, deviceId=2, source=0x00001002)
D/dalvikvm(32180): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1290K, 33% free 6329K/9351K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
V/        (  395): void cb_onMotion(uint16_t)
D/AndroidRuntime(  361): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  361): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ba4300)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at com.weg.ecatalogfragment.drawing.DrawingScreenFragment.createDrawableFromURL(DrawingScreenFragment.java:430)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at com.weg.ecatalogfragment.drawing.DrawingScreenFragment.handleResponse(DrawingScreenFragment.java:399)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at com.weg.ecatalogfragment.drawing.DrawingScreenFragment.access$0(DrawingScreenFragment.java:342)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at com.weg.ecatalogfragment.drawing.DrawingScreenFragment$1.dispatchMessage(DrawingScreenFragment.java:148)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  395):   Force finishing activity com.weg.ecatalogfragment/.ECatalogFragmentActivity
W/ActivityManager(  395): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41eff160 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/.ECatalogFragmentActivity}
I/ActivityManager(  395): No longer want com.google.android.partnersetup (pid 32633): hidden #16
I/Process (  361): Sending signal. PID: 361 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(  395): Process com.weg.ecatalogfragment (pid 361) has died.
I/WindowState(  395): WIN DEATH: Window{4263ad58 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}
I/WindowState(  395): WIN DEATH: Window{4243db28 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/com.weg.ecatalogfragment.ECatalogFragmentActivity paused=false}
W/InputMethodManagerService(  395): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 361 uid 10111
W/BackupManagerService(  395): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.providers.settings' uid=10035
W/InputMethodManagerService(  395): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@424578c0 attribute=null
W/ActivityManager(  395): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{41eff160 com.weg.ecatalogfragment/.ECatalogFragmentActivity}
I/ActivityManager(  395): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher u=0} from pid 395
I/Gmail   (32707): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 1359460, normalSync: true
D/dalvikvm(32180): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1421K, 31% free 6532K/9351K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
D/dalvikvm(32707): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3952K, 64% free 2963K/8195K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 52ms
I/Gmail   (32707): MainSyncRequestProto: lowestBkwdConvoId: 0, highestHandledServerOp: 1359460, normalSync: true
I/Gmail   (32707): lowestBackward conversation id 0
I/ActivityManager(  395): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.jtb.alogcat/.LogActivity u=0} from pid 817
```

And the code of the specified ECatalogFragment class is:

```
public class ECatalogFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{

    private static final String ImageButton = null;
    private Fragment homeScreenFragment;
    private Fragment imageFragment;
    private ImageButton _pdfIcon=null;
    private TextView _pdfText=null;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            int count=fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
            System.out.println("gdfgdgcvbccccccccccccccccccc "+count);
            for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {    
                fm.popBackStack();
            }

            //  fm.popBackStack(null,android.app.FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            _pdfIcon=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pdf_icon);
            _pdfIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

            _pdfText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pdf_txt);
            _pdfText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _pdfIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        RelativeLayout rel =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.top_right_datasheet_relative_layout);
        if (rel == null) {
        } else {
            /**
             * First Method:
             * leftFragment is added in main.xml and here we get a reference to the fragment
             */
            homeScreenFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.homescreen_frag);

            /**
             * Second Method:
             * topRightFragment is not defined in main.xml.  Management is done all in code.
             * top_right_relative_layout is a relative layout in main.xml
             */

            imageFragment = new ImageFragment();
            fragmentTransaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.top_right_splash_relative_layout, imageFragment, "imageFragmentTag"); //First parameter is the container id
            fragmentTransaction.show(imageFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==_pdfIcon)
        {
            _pdfText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _pdfIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            GetPDFScreenFragment getPDFFragment = new GetPDFScreenFragment();
            fragmentTransaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.top_right_Drawing_relative_layout, getPDFFragment, "rightDrawingFragmentTag"); //First parameter is the container id
            fragmentTransaction.show(getPDFFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("3");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {

            int count=fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
            System.out.println("gdfgdgcvbccccccccccccccccccc "+count);

            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            {
                if(count==0)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {    
                        fm.popBackStack();
                    }                       
                    _pdfText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    _pdfIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }else if(count==1)
                {    
                    finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ECatalogFragmentActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    _pdfText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    _pdfIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
                else 
                {
                    _pdfText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    _pdfIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

Comment: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` - As user370305 suggests, you shouldn't be doing any network operations on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: Thanks for the quickest reply Squonk,I ll apply it and let you know asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Looking in your Logs..

```
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**
```

and

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  361): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

The problem is your **Network Related Lengthy operation** on `MainUIThread`. which Android 4.0 (ICS) not allowed.

Bad and short solution:

Put these two code lines in `onCreate()` of your Activity,

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Good but Lengthy solution:

Use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for your all Network Related operation...

I suggest you to go with **AsyncTask**..

Comment: If possible avoid Network related and All operation which are time consuming on Main UI Thread. Android gives a nice and feasible way AsyncTask for it. It also Good Application development practice for User Interface prospective.

Comment: thanks alot sir, I have changed my logic a little bit as directed by you. I am using a different thread for every Network operation in whole app. Android 4.0 do not digest even a % bad programming.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot for Suggestions.
 I am using a different thread for every Network operation in whole app. Android 4.0 do not digest even a % bad programming.
As I experienced in Android OS 4.0, not single image download operation can not be done on UI thread.
DO NOT PERFORM ANY NETWORK OPERATION ON MAIN UI THREAD IN ANDROID, especially in 4.0.